# API mailchimp : failed to connect

Tags: php, mailchimp

Using the PHP script below I get a "failed to connect" message.

Is it correct that I press ENABLE in my account settings for the API Key ?

```
<?php

echo "testing" ;

$api_key = "......";
$list_id = "a45e802adf";

require('src/Mailchimp.php');
$Mailchimp = new Mailchimp( $api_key );
$Mailchimp_Lists = new Mailchimp_Lists( $Mailchimp );
$subscriber = $Mailchimp_Lists->subscribe( $list_id, array( 'email' => "testing@yahoo.de" ) );

if ( ! empty( $subscriber['leid'] ) ) {
    // Success
}


?>
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mailchimp_HttpError' with message
>   'API call to lists/subscribe failed: Failed to connect to
>   us3.api.mailchimp.com port 443: Connection refused' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\src\Mailchimp.php:221 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\src\Mailchimp\Lists.php(743):
>   Mailchimp->call('lists/subscribe', Array) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\tochimp.php(14):
>   Mailchimp_Lists->subscribe('a45e802adf', Array) #2 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\src\Mailchimp.php on line 221

Comment: in the error message you have a 'Connection refused'. So I think you did something wrong with the authentication. 

- Are you using the right $api_key?

Comment: Well i go to Account Settings -> API keys i generate a key and set it to ENABLE and then copy and paste it .

Tried  this if it was something with CURL http://redwebturtle.blogspot.gr/2013/09/mailchimp-api-v20-ssl-error-solution.html

but no solution

Comment: It seems there were some problems with Firewall settings and the machine i was running it from.

Comment: Cool that you could solve it.